# AWS Lambda not able to update all records

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES mail with nodemailer. When the email is send, the the message Id created for that email is stored in my DB. Once the email is received by recipient, with the help of SNS I receive a notification email and a lambda is triggered. I am using this lambda to get the updated status of email and update the same in my DB. I have created the lambda function by uploading the package zip folder in AWS.

When I send one email , email is sent and lambda is  able to update the DB. 
But if I send 10 email at once , all the emails are sent but lambda is updating only 5-8 records.

Mysql : 2.18.1
NODE: 12.x

PFB code of Lambda,

```
const config = require("./config.json");


const getConnectionPool = ( dbname ) => {
  const params = {
    host: config.dbhost,
    user: config.dbuser,
    password: config.dbpassword,
    database: dbname,
    multipleStatements: true,
    // debug:true
  }
  const pool = mysql.createPool( params );
  return pool;
}

const getParameters = ( event ) => {
  const data =event.Records[0];
  let eventType = 0;
  const record = JSON.parse(data.Sns.Message);

  const mail =  record.mail;
  const headers = mail.headers[3];
  let dbname  = headers.value;
  dbname = dbname.replace("<", "");
  dbname = dbname.replace(">", "");

  if( record.eventType == "Delivery" ) {
    eventType = 2;
  } else if( record.eventType == "Bounce" ) {
    eventType = 3;
  }else if( record.eventType == "Complaint" ) {
    eventType = 4;
  }else if( record.eventType == "Reject" ) {
    eventType = 5;
  }
  return {
    eventType: eventType,
    messageId: mail.messageId,
    dbname: dbname
  }
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  let params  = getParameters( event );


  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const pool = getConnectionPool( params.dbname );

  pool.getConnection( (err, connection) => {
    // Use the connection
     connection.query(
      "START TRANSACTION;SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;update email_logs set bool_is_sent = " + mysql.escape( params.eventType ) + " where message_id= " + mysql.escape( params.messageId ) + ";SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;COMMIT;", 
       (error, results ) => {

        // And done with the connection.
        connection.release();
        // Handle error after the release.
        if (error) callback(error);
        else callback(null, results[0]);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Just a snippet of cloudwatch log

```
OkPacket {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 0,
    insertId: 0,
    serverStatus: 43,
    warningCount: 0,
    message: '(Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
    protocol41: true,
    changedRows: 0
  },
```

What's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If SNS receives multiple updates for different emails at the same time, it's possible that your lambda function will receive bundled records in a single event (so your lambda could be for example triggered 3 times for 10 Updates).

You're only accessing the first Record (`event.Records[0]`), but there could be multiple.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was,lambda got called first then the message Id get stored in the Db. Due to this the lambda was not getting the records for update and I was getting 0 affectedRows.